# Multi-threading variation takes much longer

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

So I have the following function:

```
void do_thing(std::vector<some_class*> some_class_vector)
{
    size_t items_to_process = some_class_vector.size();
    for (i = 0; i < items_to_process; i++)
    {
        some_class_vector[i]->compute();
    }
}
```

and I call it with something like this:

```
Timer time;
time.start();
do_thing(my_vector);
time.stop();
printf("%d", time.time);
```

And it tells me it takes, on average, something like 80 microseconds to run.
My processor has 8 cores, and when I look at the task manager I see that the computer is 13% busy when it's running that piece of code.
Since compute() doesn't change anything outside of the some_class it's called from, I decided to parallelise it, so now the code looks like

```
import <omp.h>
void do_thing(std::vector<some_class*> some_class_vector)
{
    size_t items_to_process = some_class_vector.size();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(6)
    for (i = 0; i < items_to_process; i++)
    {
        some_class_vector[i]->compute();
    }
}
```

And I run it again and now it takes about 200 microseconds to run.
And then under advice from a colleague I run it a third time like this:

```
import <omp.h>
void do_thing(std::vector<some_class*> some_class_vector)
{
    size_t items_to_process = some_class_vector.size();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(6)
    for (i = 0; i < items_to_process; i++)
    {
        some_class_vector[(10039*i) % items_to_process]->compute();
    }
}
```

And now it takes about 20 microseconds to run.
What exactly is going on here?

Comment: 80 microseconds is not a long time. I would test against something that takes a little while to run in a single thread. There is a non-zero overhead to parallelizing anything, and it may be that you have not given the program enough work to make it worthwhile.

Comment: If you measure 1000 loops over do_thing(my_vector); the timings have the same relationship?

Comment: @AndyG That might explain the increase in running time going from 1 thread to 6 threads, but not the decrease going from 6 threads to 6 threads and shuffling the vector

Comment: @Konstantin I tried making the loop in do_thing execute compute() 10 times instead of once (it's idempotent) and I had the same relationship between 1 thread and 6 threads, but I didn't try it with the vector shuffle (the last example). The application I'm working on is a simulation that, among other things, runs do_thing in a loop, and the timings I took were an average of how long do_thing takes to execute.

Comment: @MatanNov: Agreed with you there. I think West may be on to something with their answer. Operations on `std::vector` are fast because the elements are near each other. When you have a thread pulling in data from the very end of the vector contending with a thread pulling in data from the very beginning of the vector, you'll have caching issues. I think a more optimal approach would be to actually have the threads be striding by `num_threads` rather than `1` so that they all operate on data most likely to be in cache. That is, for 3 threads, thread 1 would access indices 0, 3, 6, ..., etc.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use some performance analysis tool such as Paraver (http://www.bsc.es/computer-sciences/performance-tools/paraver) or Vampir (http://www.paratools.com/Vampir) to explore whatever the application is doing in OpenMP. They allow you not only to explore the activity of each thread, but also capture information regarding CPUs (such as cache & TLB misses, instructions executed, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be data contention for the multiple cores. Now you are doing psuedorandom access of the things you are computing and thus all of the cores are no longer contending for the same cache line. Apparently there are modes in [intel VTune](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads) that will allow you to do performance analysis to catch these kind of errors. Along with some papers interesting research papers and projects from [MIT](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/commit/papers/2013/falsesharing-sc13.pdf) and [Umass](https://github.com/plasma-umass/Predator).

Comment: that's sound like right answer. do you know any way to measure CPU cache contentions?

Comment: No those are internal to the processor there is no way to really expose that information that I've ever heard of.

Comment: [These people](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/commit/papers/2013/falsesharing-sc13.pdf) do not agree with your last statement.

Comment: I never really heard of that method before certainly worth a look to characterize hardware.

Comment: @West, There are performance tools that can detect sharing and false sharing. See <https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads> for instance.

Comment: This sounds right, I'll look into the tools you linked and see if this is definitely the cause.